# Monstera: 2 new stalks, only one survived?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, monstera

Recently 2 new stalks started simultaneously to grow from the same base of my *Monstera*. You can see them below:

[image]

You've probably noticed that one thrived and became a beautiful new leaf! The other stopped pretty early and suddenly and got this odd brown ending appearing. Here's a zoom on this:

[image]

1. Any idea what is this thing and what could have happened here?
2. What should I do with this? Cut it off? Cut at the base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Aroids such as *Monstera deliciousa* puts out one leaf at a time and do not really have energy to put out multiple leaves at the same time on the same stem.

For some reason yours has started to put out two leaves but it did not have enough energy to finish both of them.

Such new leaf browning, withering could occur in case of overwatering or due to pests but given the other leaf is nice and beautiful I would rule these options out.

Generally you do not have to do anything with this failed leaf but if the look bothers you, you can trim of the tip, or the whole patio at the base of the stem. Just make sure not to damage the main stem itself.